# Joysticks for PCB design that are better to use than classical mouse

Tags: pcb

I suppose there are some tools (joysticks or something) that professional PCB designers use instead of mouse for PCB routing.

Would you be so kind to share with me your experience in that sense ?

Thanks,

Bojan.

Comment: I just use a mouse. I was surprised to realize that sometimes I'll just skip the mouse and just use the trackpad when I have to use the keyboard a lot - even though I have the mouse plugged in and right by my hand.

Comment: Try a Koala pad and a Trackball and avoid RSI

Comment: I prefer a trackball for most computer use. But Altium just doesn't work well with one, and I switch to a mouse when using Altium.

Answer (score 3):

> I suppose there are some tools (joysticks or something) that professional PCB designers use instead of mouse for PCB routing.

Why? What's wrong with a mouse?

I've dealt with various PCB designers (the lab I worked for had about a half-dozen people doing it), and it was all done on PCs with mice.

Any PCB layout software will use a quantized grid of pixels, usually on the order of .001 inches or maybe less, and mice work just fine for dealing with such an array.

Comment: I'm not saying anything is wrong with a mouse. I just liked to know if there is a tool specialized for PCB layout and used by professionals. When speaking about mice, is there any model you can recommend that is appropriate for PCB layout? :-)

Comment: After "gaming" mice, next niche is "PCB layout mice" :D IMO a specialized keyboard would be more useful though..

Answer (score 2):

The mouse is sub-optimal for CAD work because it doesn't have means to draw straight vertical or horizontal lines independently; rolling the mouse is always off, which requires an additional move to correct position and therefore wastes designer time. In deep past we used to have devices with two "[Thumb Wheels](http://mvscad.blogspot.com/2012/08/cursor-control-devices.html)" to control trace placement, horizontally, and vertically.

[image]

Another disadvantage of mouse as a CAD pointing device is that end actions usually require some click, which also usually affects the cursor position and places the end point slightly wrong, which again require additional "grab and place" corrective action and again is a waste of time. In thumbwheel devices the actions were performed by other hand using designated control keys on a normal keyboard.

Unfortunately, these devices are no longer manufactured, I think.
But these days [this article](https://blog.grabcad.com/blog/2010/08/28/best-for-cad-work-mouse-trackball-3d-device/) would probably point you to the best pointer for CAD.
Still all of these pointers came from gaming area, and not specifically for CAD.

Comment: Some graphic softwares (Illustrator and I think Photoshop too) have shortcuts for horizontal or vertical lines (you press shift and you are constrained orthogonally).

Comment: @WesleyLee, thanks, it is good to know that some software houses know what they are doing and are taking care of right functions. Next time I will check for this kind of abilities in my tools. Still, if it takes another hand to be busy holding something, the end action will be still sub-optimal. A foot pedal maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience of working with an expert PCB designer (expert by my own opinion), they worked very well with the keyboard.

Learning keyboard shortcuts for a given program can increase productivity massively, particularly for enabling and changing the settings of snap-to, i.e. for when you are aligning components and tracks to a grid.

Some things I find particularly useful are disabling the secondary functions of the function keys on a keyboard (you don't want to start playing music when you're trying to turn a grid on!). I actually switch from using a trackpad in general work to using a mouse for PCB design as I like keeping the sensitivity of the mouse higher than that of the trackpad. Also click-and-drag I find easier with a mouse.

I suppose the point I'm trying to make is that with your own experience you'll find a set of tools that helps you work the most efficiently, it's about trying things out!

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend the SpaceMouse from https://www.3dconnexion.de.
I used them for many years in PCB design with Altium Designer. You get best results if you use the SpaceMouse with one hand and a standard mouse with the other (strong) hand.

You have to get used a little bit to navigate with this 3D SpaceMouse, but once learned, you will never want to miss that again. (Btw: I have no shares for this company/product, I‘m just a big fan of it :-)